# Permutations for paths

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> What is the counting sequence for paths from $$(0,0)\text{ to }(n,n)$$ where $$2n$$ is the size of the path (number of steps) and n can vary over all nonnegative integers.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I know that in general, # of paths from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ is $(m+n)!\,/(m!n!)$ where m and n denote $(c-a)$ and $(d-b)$ respectively. But this size of the path $2n$ confuses me.

Comment: I think it's just saying that the path must contain $2n$ steps.  If you don't have this constraint, there are infinitely many paths since we're allowed to travel to any point in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about the size implies that you go only $\rightarrow, \uparrow.$

Hence, the answer is 
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}.$$

This represents that you choose $n$ $(\rightarrow s)$ in $2n$ steps. Of course, the order matters.

For example, when $n=3$, what you want is the number of permutations of $\rightarrow \rightarrow \rightarrow \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow$, which is $6!/(3!\cdot 3!).$

Comment: Isn't that a combination formula? Sorry I'm not clear on permutation/combination syntax

Comment: Well, yes. Do you understand why $(2n)!/(n!n!)$? If yes, this is the same as $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Yes I understand that. It's just kind of confusing that order matters and when order matters, to my knowledge it is not represented as a combinatorial sequence. Or maybe I have a deep misunderstanding going on here.

Comment: OK. $(2n)!/(n!n!)$ represents the permutation of $n$ $\rightarrow$s and $n$ $\uparrow$s. On the other hand, $\binom{2n}{n}$ represents to choose $n$ places of $\rightarrow$s. ($n$ $\uparrow$s are placed in the $n$ places left) As a result, these two are the same.

Comment: @user121449 $2$ represents the number of arms I have, but it also happens to represent the number of legs I have. When there are only two types of things to write down in some order - right arrows and up arrows - and the number of each is fixed, a choice of ordering is equivalent to a choice of positions for (say) the left arrows.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the number of paths from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ given $c \geq a$ and $d \geq b$ is

$$\binom{m+n}{n} = \binom{m+n}{m} = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!\cdot n!} $$

**where the steps go up and to the right only.** (Otherwise our paths might be arbitrarily long.)

So for your question, a path going from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ where the steps go up and to right is equivalent to a sequence of $2n$ steps consisting of $n$ steps to the right and $n$ steps up.

Once we have chosen the position of the steps up, the steps to the right are all forced so the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ is $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Doesn't the order matter?

Comment: @user121449 Yes, what's your point?

Comment: Yes. For instance a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$ might go: right, right, up, up or right, up, right, up. In either case choosing the positions of the "ups" is sufficient so $\binom{4}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess information about size path is redundant and can be simply ignored.
Length (or size) of the shortest path from (0,0) to (n,n) IS 2n.

Your approach is correct and the answer would be (2n)!/(n!n!)